# How can I find out which of my accounts triggered my Association Bonus?

Tags: discussion, association, association-bonus

WOW, just 3 minutes ago, SE just told me I got +1800 points. At first, I thought this was some kind of joke, but then I found out it was because I just earned something called an Association Bonus on all of my accounts. I don't know what to say, but last time I was this kind of happy was the day I used my own hard-earned money to buy my father a wallet.

After the excitement, I still don't know:

- How did I get this Association Bonus?
- Apparently it's triggered by one of my accounts passing 200 rep - how can I tell which of my accounts triggered this? Suppose I have two accounts on two sites - one at 198 rep, the other at 197 rep - and the next morning I find I got an association bonus, how can I find out which of these accounts triggered it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm pretty sure the asker's still getting stuck on one point. @AveMaleficum I've edited your question to try to make this part of your question clearer, please check it to see if it still makes sense and is asking what you're trying to ask. By the way, congrats on the +1800!! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the others have pointed out: you get an association bonus for crossing the 200 rep mark on any site.

#### How do you check *which site* gave you the bonus, though?

It's not going to be clear, and there's nothing I'm aware of that'll tell you which site exactly triggered the association bonus.

But let's take your 197 and 198 rep accounts example, and pretend they each get +10 reputation from an upvote overnight. *Either* of them could've been the one raised over the 200 mark first, and given both a +100 association bonus. Unless both upvotes occur within milliseconds of each other, though, there's going to be a telltale hint:

On one site, you'll get the +10 upvote then +100 association bonus. On the other site, you'll have the +100 association bonus hit first from the other account, *then* a +10 upvote.

So you just have to know which site got the upvote first. You can do this by visiting your [reputation page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/249173/ave-maleficum?tab=reputation) for those two accounts. You're going to see those +10's and +100's there, and you can sleuth it out with the power of mathematics.

[image: MATHEMATICAL!]

Comment: All Hail to Mathematics!

Answer (score 4):

The only site in which you passed 200 rep prior to getting the association bonus is this site - Meta - which gave you a 100 rep in each of the other sites in which you have an account.

Comment: If I have two sites, one is 198 rep the other is 197 rep, and the next morning I find I get asooication bonus. The question is, I don't know what happened last night, so how can I know which site gives me assocation bonus?

Comment: @AveMaleficum - It's simple. The site which gave you association bonus point is the one which has 300 or more reputation on the next day. If more than two sites have 300+ rep, then you have to see the timestamp of the reputation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific site, to which if you join, you get bonus point. The definition of bonus point is that, Once you have 200 reputation on a singe site and then if you join another of SE sites, you get 100 bonus reputation.

No matter which of the site you join, You always get bonus reputation.

[Bonus Definition on Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

---

> If I have two sites, one is 198 rep the other is 197 rep, and the next morning I find I get association bonus. The question is, I don't know what happened last night, so how can I know which site gives me association bonus?

In this case it may possible that some user vote up a question or answer of your to any site, and due to this you cross 200 reputation on one site and you got bonus reputation. Now it may possible that the use un-done his vote and that's why you have no reputation history for it. For this kind of action, you do not loos your bonus points.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I want to specially which site passes 200 points to give me Association Bonus.

Comment: Any site. If you have 200 reputation on any site and you join another of SE site then you get 100 bonus reputation.